# MariaDB stored procedure select statement only returning single row

Tags: mysql

I have created the following stored procedure which creates a table with multiple rows.

The select statement should return multiple rows as well, however it is only returning a single row.

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_loadMarginAllocations;
CREATE  PROCEDURE sp_loadMarginAllocations(IN  leid INT(10))
BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT(10);
    DECLARE accountId VARCHAR(64);
    DECLARE myCursor CURSOR FOR SELECT ca.account_id FROM account_balance ca WHERE ca.legal_entity_id =leid;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE if exists margin_balances;

    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE margin_balances (
       cptyName VARCHAR(64)  DEFAULT NULL,
        cptyAccountId VARCHAR(64) DEFAULT NULL,
        qtyLocked4us decimal(32,9) DEFAULT 0.00,
        accountId VARCHAR(64) DEFAULT NULL,
        qtyLocked4cpty decimal(32,9) DEFAULT 0.00,
        trades INT(7) DEFAULT 0
    );
    SET done = 0;

    OPEN myCursor;
    my_loop: LOOP
        FETCH NEXT FROM myCursor INTO accountId;
        IF done THEN
            LEAVE my_loop;
        END IF;

        INSERT INTO margin_balances (cptyName, cptyAccountId, qtyLocked4us, accountId, qtyLocked4cpty, trades)
            SELECT t1.taker_account_name as cptyName, t1.taker_account_id AS cptyAccountId, SUM(t1.maker_amount) AS qtyLocked4us,
                t2.maker_account_id AS accountId, SUM(t2.taker_amount) AS qtyLocked4cpty, COUNT(*) AS trades
                FROM collateral_trade t1, collateral_trade t2 WHERE t1.collateral_id = t2.collateral_id
                AND (t1.maker_account_id = accountId )  UNION all
            SELECT t1.maker_account_name as cptyName, t1.maker_account_id AS cptyAccountId, SUM(t1.taker_amount) AS qtyLocked4us,
                t2.taker_account_id AS accountId, SUM(t2.maker_amount) AS qtyLocked4cpty, COUNT(*) AS trades
                FROM collateral_trade t1, collateral_trade t2 WHERE t1.collateral_id = t2.collateral_id
                AND (t1.taker_account_id = accountId  );

    END LOOP;

    CLOSE myCursor;
    SELECT * FROM margin_balances WHERE trades != 0 GROUP BY accountId;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
call sp_loadMarginAllocations(243);
```

result:

```
MariaDB [test_table]> call sp_loadMarginAllocations(243);
+-----------------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+--------+
| cptyName              | cptyAccountId  | qtyLocked4us   | accountId      | qtyLocked4cpty | trades |
+-----------------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+--------+
| JPM1 PartyB Custodian | jpm1@custodian | 1874.000000000 | jpm1@custodian | 1127.000000000 |     78 |
+-----------------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+--------+
1 row in set (0.006 sec)
```

Table looks like this when select statement run manually (and what I want to see from the SP):

```
+-----------------------+-------------------+----------------+-------------------+----------------+--------+
| cptyName              | cptyAccountId     | qtyLocked4us   | accountId         | qtyLocked4cpty | trades |
+-----------------------+-------------------+----------------+-------------------+----------------+--------+
| NULL                  | NULL              |           NULL | NULL              |           NULL |      0 |
| JPM1 PartyB Custodian | jpm1@custodian    | 1874.000000000 | jpm1@custodian    | 1127.000000000 |     78 |
| Z-PartyA              | zedclient@enduser |  413.000000000 | zedmaster@enduser |  513.000000000 |      9 |
+-----------------------+-------------------+----------------+-------------------+----------------+--------+
```

Comment: What is the result of the cursor select, do you checked if it runs more than once?

Comment: You are also missing `GROUP BY`s on both `SELECT`s inside the loop. Hint: if you mix normal columns with aggregate functions in `SELECT`, use a `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Wow....`SELECT * ... GROUP BY`.

Comment: Also use proper `JOIN`.  It's been around for over 25 years.

Comment: I am sure if you learn to use `GROUP BY` properly, your problem will be automatically resolved.  There are tons of example in the web.  Here's just one of them. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-group-by/